Search for a statistical test to analyze the "home ground advantage" for rugby matches
I have a database of results from club-level rugby-union matches. It has results from a number of European leagues/competititions over about 15 years. I am trying to do some analysis on the 'home ground' effect (this is a well known phenomonen in almost all sports where teams tend to perform better at their home ground/court/field than when they are away). For example, Team X playing Team Y at home will on average win by Z more points than Team X playing Team Y away from home. Note that while many of the games have X and Y in the same country, many do not.
I would like to test a hypothesis that "The degree of home advantage is different when playing a team from another country"
I am struggling a little to define an appropriate test statistic to use to test my hypothesis.

If the score difference home team - away team in match $x$ is $d_x$ then a natural test statistic might be $\overline{d_n} - \overline{d_i}$ comparing the average differences in matches between teams in the same nation with the average differences in matches between teams playing internationally.  You would then reject the "no difference null hypothesis" if this statistic is too far from $0$.

There is a question of what you do if some pairs of teams do not play both ways round.  This becomes a more serious issue if there is a seeding system in which the better-ranked team is given home advantage by the rules of the competition, as happens in some play-offs in some sports, and you might want to exclude such matches.

Thank you for the prompt and helpful answer @Henry.
If I understand it correctly, what I should do is create a statistic and use a t-distribution to test whether that statistic is singificantly different from zero. The t-value would be (sample mean-0)/(sample standard deviation/sqrt(n)), with degrees of freedom=n-1.

What I'm wondering is whether n is based on the raw data, or number of calculated data points. For example if I have a home advantage collected for 10 pairs of teams (6 in country and 4 'out of' country), but each home advantage is calculated based on 25 games, am I using n=10 or n=250?
